# uncaught type error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to merge metro panel jquery and isotope jquery with this functions then i am getting this uncaught type error in jquery.

While i am loading the page 1st time its working but after that its not working and giving this error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(window).load(function() {  

$('#metropanel').metropanel({
```

**`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method`**

```
'metropanel'  
 mpPosition:'left',  
  mpMainItemBg: '#353535',  
  mpSubmenuBg: '#353535',  
  mpActiveItem:'transparent-smoke',  
  mpHoverItem:'transparent-blue',  
  contentPosition:'related',  
  contentEffect:'slideLeft',  
  contentEffectDuration:400,  
  MainListScrollBarStyle: 'solid-olive',  
  SubmenuScrollBarStyle: 'solid-blue',  
  mpState:1,  
  MainItemDisplay:8  
 });  

$(document).ready(function() {  
        $("body").append("<div id='divSmallBoxes'></div>");  
        $("body").append("<div id='divMiniIcons'></div><div id='divbigBoxes'></div>");  
        $(".OpenSideBar").pageslide({ direction: "left" });
 });  
});
```

How to solve it?

Comment: your browser console should give you source filename and line number

Comment: Most likely you forgot or failed to load the plugin, or typoed the method name.

Comment: @ArunPJohny:  I am not getting anything at console.

Comment: i think "metropanel" is undefined as a function to $('#metropanel').
what is metropanel, and where is it defined ?

Comment: @IdanHen: #metropanel is css class.

Comment: $('#metropanel').metropanel({});

Comment: #metropanel is css class bind with metropanel function which is defined in query.

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja: metropanel is not defined in query. You will need to load a separate plugin for jQuery.